# How do I send e-mails through Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

I'm having difficulty sending email notifications through DBMS_SCHEDULER.

I've gone through instructions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/scheduse008.htm#CIAIEJEJ) on adding email notifications and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/schedadmin001.htm#CHDCCDFD) on configuring the mail server but I still don't get any e-mails sent. I'm using the same mail server settings on UTL_MAIL (to send mail using procedures) and Oracle Enterprise Manager (To get backup and availability email and they work fine.) I would rather not use UTL_MAIL instead as it doesn't offer the simplicity and flexibility I'm hoping to achieve with scheduler emails.

Below we have what server settings I've configured and how I'm trying to create a job that will send notifications.

```
/*Settings*/

exec  dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('email_server','xxx');

exec  dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('email_sender','Scheduler@domain.com');

/* Dont think this is needed but added anyway, this allows UTL_MAIL to work*/

alter system set smtp_out_server = 'xxx';
begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl (
    acl         => 'dbms_scheduler.xml',
    description => 'Allow mail to be send',
    principal   => 'SCHEMA',
    is_grant    => TRUE,
    privilege   => 'connect'
    );
    commit;
end;

begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege (
  acl       => 'dbms_scheduler.xml',
  principal => 'SCHEMA',
  is_grant  => TRUE,
  privilege => 'resolve'
  );
  commit;
end;

begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl(
  acl  => 'dbms_scheduler.xml',
  host => 'xxx'
  );
  commit;
end;

/*Create a quick, simple job*/

BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
            job_name => '"SCHEMA"."EMAIL_TEST"',
            job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
            job_action => 'SCHEMA.DO_MOD',
            number_of_arguments => 0,
            start_date => NULL,
            repeat_interval => NULL,
            end_date => NULL,
            enabled => FALSE,
            auto_drop => FALSE,
            comments => '');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"SCHEMA"."EMAIL_TEST"', 
             attribute => 'restartable', value => TRUE);


    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"SCHEMA"."EMAIL_TEST"', 
             attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_RUNS);
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"SCHEMA"."EMAIL_TEST"', 
             attribute => 'raise_events', value => '511');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.ADD_JOB_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION (    
             job_name => '"SCHEMA"."EMAIL_TEST"', 
             recipients => 'user@xxx',
             sender => 'oracle@xxx',
             subject => 'Oracle Scheduler Job Notification - %job_owner%.%job_name%.%job_subname% %event_type%',
             body => 'Job: %job_owner%.%job_name%.%job_subname%
Event: %event_type%
Date: %event_timestamp%
Log id: %log_id%
Job class: %job_class_name%
Run count: %run_count%
Failure count: %failure_count%
Retry count: %retry_count%
Error code: %error_code
%Error message: %error_message%',
             events => 'job_started, job_broken, job_chain_stalled, job_completed, job_disabled, job_failed, job_over_max_dur, job_run_completed, job_sch_lim_reached, job_stopped, job_succeeded',
                filter_condition => NULL 
             );
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
             name => '"SCHEMA"."EMAIL_TEST"');
END;
```

This code all completes successfully but I get no emails. I can also see the entries in user_scheduler_notifications but receive nothing.

Comment: If it doesn't error out are you **really** there is a problem? Can you try another email address for example?

Comment: @mmmmmpie I've tried on a few different accounts. I don't have access to the SMTP server so can't really check from there but as mentioned I've been able to send mail from non-existent to internal ones without authentication in other places. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I suggesting attempting to send mail from the actual server itself using sendmail or whatever utility it has. What is the OS version? Also who are you granting the privilege of sending email to?